# How to list table definition from different database?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a linked server with name my database, I would like to know the table definition of a certain table.

I try with this query but it does not work.

My linked server name is `[STUDETAIL]`

Query:

```
 select c.*
 from sys.columns c
 inner join sys.synonyms s on c.object_id = object_id(s.base_object_name)
 where s.name = '[STUDETAIL].[dbo].[Student]'
```

May I know is there any other solution ?

Answer (score 0):

the link server name should be on the FROM clause

```
FROM [STUDETAIL].[database name].[sys].[columns] c
```